# How to see click throughs for Google Plus posts?

Tags: google-plus, analytics

I'm relatively new to Google Plus. As far as I can tell, it's impossible to see click throughs via the platform. Click the "down arrow" in the upper right corner of a post and you will see this menu:

[image: Google Plus Activity]

"View post activity" will show you +1's and reshares, but no click through data. And Dashboard view doesn't seem to provide this info either.

Is it possible to track clicks on posted links in Google Plus?

Comment: Not available to us mere mortals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Plus has no native option to track clicks on posted links, but you can use any link tracking system like [Google URL Builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en).